org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: expected
I am using below driver and dependency packages
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
            <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc-fips</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-fips</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

and the problem is unable to run the code successfully
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: expected [9f6751f059ab42f7d83e4e107881438036787e1e1821cd23a53c4b8181cc300f] got [d337b151b2df89731bc175d9a9f47b4d5103dba8b58f00b7534958368db0bc36]
I am trying to connect snowflake connection using FIPS driver . But I am getting this error org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed:
How to resolve this issue. please help on this

The error comes from the bc-fips jar, which has an internal checksum calculation (a FIPS requirement) that means you cannot modify or repackage the jar in any way. So you should check on your usage of that jar.

Just  we are doing this " java -cp ${module}/target/${module}-test-${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}-jar-with-dependencies.jar test.${module}.Main MAKE_MANIFEST". Main .java file I called this Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());

I need  bc-fips jar for BouncyCastleFipsProvider

bc-fips jar is part of snowflake jdbc fips .
